# Error 3194 (Run diagno - "Secure connection with itunes store failed")

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, restore, software-update

Actually i have a iPhone4 with iOS 6.1.3 and I want to update it with iOS 7.0 or restore the same iOS (6.1.3).
But every time just after the "verify" iTunes throw an Error with error code 3194.
And when I runned "run diagnostic" then in Network Connection step, "secure connection with iTunes store failed".

I tried 5 different computer (XP and Win 2K8) with 3 different kind of Internet connections (broadband and DSL), also antivirus was uninstalled, hosts file set to its default parameter based on Microsoft guidance, tried DFU mode (in DFU mode error code 4000) etc etc but error remains same.

My cell is purchased in Ukraine and now I'm in india. When iOS 6.1.3 was released, than I successfully updated my iPhone with the same pc but now its creating the problem.

So can anybody help me to shortout this problem...

Thanks & regards

Comment: Is it just for update?  I.e. can do normal app store purchases?   Which country's Istore are you connecting with?

Comment: Thanks @joop for your reply. For both upgrade and restore. Yes, i can normally purchase/download from iTunes Store. Connecting with India iTunes Store.